# Why is 'before' a Downward Entailing Operator, but 'after' is not?

Tags: syntax, semantics, entailment

I'm a teaching assistant for a linguistics class and I'm having a hard time finding a clear and concise way to explain the difference between "before" and "after" re: entailment.

The textbook gives the following examples:

(a) *Sam smiles *after* he puts on any socks.

(b) Sam smiles *before* he puts on any socks.

I know that (a) is ungrammatical because the Negative Polarity Item "any" is not c-commanded by a Downward Entailing Operator; however, I'm having a hard time articulating to this student why "before" is a Downward Entailing Operator, but "after" is not...

If anyone has any suggestions, explanations, or examples, they would be much appreciated!

Comment: A isn’t ungrammatical, surely. It just requires _any_ to be used in the sense ‘any at all’ (e.g., not just red ones, but any socks at all).

Comment: Isn't it because _before X_ doesn't necessarily entail _X_, but _after X_ does? _I shouted at him before he said something foolish_ might be mechanically interpreted as meaning that he said some foolish, but pragmatically it usually means that he didn't.

Comment: _He said "Get him out of here before the Dean sees him", and we did get him out before the Dean saw him_ does not entail that the Dean saw him. It's the diff between past, in memory, and future, in imagination. One's automatically irrealis and the other ain't.